# How to add a column by LINQ to SQL (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, linq

![Put image here!][1]

This is the image of my project.

I need to add a sex column to the SQL database using LINQ (C#).

CLass Add:

```
public bool addNhanvien(string manv, string tennv, string ngaysinh, string chucvu, string sdt,
        string sex,
        string diachi, string quequan, string bangcap, string bophan)
    {
        NhanVien nv = new NhanVien();
        nv.MaNV = manv;
        nv.TenNV = tennv;
        nv.Ngaysinh = Convert.ToDateTime(ngaysinh);
        nv.Sex = sex;
        nv.Chucvu = chucvu;
        nv.SDT = Convert.ToInt32(sdt);
        nv.Diachi = diachi;
        nv.Quequan = quequan;
        nv.Bangcap = bangcap;
        nv.Bophan = bophan;
        qlysach.NhanViens.InsertOnSubmit(nv);

        try
        {
            qlysach.SubmitChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Class button Add

```
if (nhanvien.addNhanvien(txtMaNV.Text, txtTenNV.Text, txtNgaySinh.Text,
            grpSex.Text, txtxSDT.Text,
            cboxChucVu.Text,  txtDiaChi.Text, txtQueQuan.Text,
            cboxBangCap.Text, cboxBoPhan.Text) == true)
        {
            dtgQuanlynhanvien.DataSource = nhanvien.getAllNV();
            MessageBox.Show("successfull");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
```

It throws an error [which error?].

Thank you so much!

Comment: Just returning false and swallowing exception wouldn't help. Catch exception in a variable , log it/put a break point and view it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Vietnamese, but it looks like you added the new parameters in the wrong place in your calling function:

```
public bool addNhanvien(string manv, string tennv, string ngaysinh, 
    string chucvu, string sdt,
    string sex,
    string diachi, string quequan, string bangcap, string bophan)


if (nhanvien.addNhanvien(txtMaNV.Text, txtTenNV.Text, txtNgaySinh.Text,
            grpSex.Text, txtxSDT.Text,
            cboxChucVu.Text,  txtDiaChi.Text, txtQueQuan.Text,
            cboxBangCap.Text, cboxBoPhan.Text) == true)
```

Notice that the fourth parameter is `chucvu` but you are passing in `grpSex.Text`.  The 5th and 6th parameters also look wrong.  Check the order of your parameters, but it looks like you need:

```
if (nhanvien.addNhanvien(txtMaNV.Text, txtTenNV.Text, txtNgaySinh.Text,
            cboxChucVu.Text, txtxSDT.Text, 
            grpSex.Text, 
            txtDiaChi.Text, txtQueQuan.Text, cboxBangCap.Text, cboxBoPhan.Text
   ) == true)
```

Also you should do something else instead of just returning `false` if an exception is thrown.  At the very least you could just rethrow the exception, or you could add logging to see what the error was.